# How to integrate MEF with ASP.NET MVC 4 and ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, mef

How does one integrate [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/) (MEF) with ASP.NET MVC 4 and ASP.NET Web API in the same project?

Consider an example application, with an MVC controller `HomeController` and a Web API controller `ContactController`. Both have a property of type `IContactRepository`, which they rely on MEF to resolve. The problem is how to plug MEF into MVC and Web API, so that instances are created via MEF.

**HomeController:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Home controller. Instruct MEF to create one instance of this class per importer,
/// since this is what MVC expects.
/// </summary>
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Import]
    private IContactRepository _contactRepository = null;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_contactRepository.GetAllContacts());
    }
}
```

**ContactController:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Contact API controller. Instruct MEF to create one instance of this class per importer,
/// since this is what Web API expects.
/// </summary>
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    [Import]
    private IContactRepository _contactRepo = null;

    public Contact[] Get()
    {
        return _contactRepo.GetAllContacts();
    }
}
```

**IContactRepository and ContactRepository:**

```
public interface IContactRepository
{
    Contact[] GetAllContacts();
}

[Export(typeof(IContactRepository))]
public class ContactRepository : IContactRepository
{
    public Contact[] GetAllContacts()
    {
        return new Contact[] {
            new Contact { Id = 1, Name = "Glenn Beck"},
            new Contact { Id = 2, Name = "Bill O'Riley"}
        };
    }
}
```

**Contact:**

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution is to implement [System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and [System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dependencies.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and register your implementation with ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API respectively, in your `Application_Start` method.

In this example we'll create a class `MefConfig`, which implements a method `RegisterMef` that gets called from `Application_Start` in order to install our dependency resolver. The class `MefDependencyResolver` implements both `System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver` and `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver` and, as such, handles dependency resolution duties for both MVC and Web API.

**Application_Start, Put This in Your Global.asax.cs:**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        [...]
        MefConfig.RegisterMef();
    }
}
```

**MefDependencyResolver and MefConfig:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Resolve dependencies for MVC / Web API using MEF.
/// </summary>
public class MefDependencyResolver : System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer _container;

    public MefDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to request a service implementation.
    /// 
    /// Here we call upon MEF to instantiate implementations of dependencies.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType">Type of service requested.</param>
    /// <returns>Service implementation or null.</returns>
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceType");

        var name = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType);
        var export = _container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<object>(name);
        return export;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to request service implementations.
    /// 
    /// Here we call upon MEF to instantiate implementations of dependencies.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType">Type of service requested.</param>
    /// <returns>Service implementations.</returns>
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceType");

        var exports = _container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
        return exports;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

public static class MefConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMef()
    {
        var asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = new CompositionContainer(asmCatalog);
        var resolver = new MefDependencyResolver(container);
        // Install MEF dependency resolver for MVC
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
        // Install MEF dependency resolver for Web API
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really works, thanks. For me I've just changed catalog a little bit:
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
                catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\EducationBusinessLogic\bin\Debug", "*"));
                catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested solution leads to memory leaks when used for non-shared `IDisposable` service types such as `ApiController`s because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787982/mef-keeps-reference-of-nonshared-idisposable-parts-not-allowing-them-to-be-coll. I wonder how people get around this.

Comment: FWIW, I found that [Import]s are not resolved in the ApiController class unless the ApiController class is itself exported with an [Export] attribute above the class declaration.

Comment: @Dejan I've fixed this issue and posted it as an answer below - have a look.

Answer (score 2):

@aknuds1 answer is the best I've seen so far for integrating MEF into the DependencyResolver. I was able to extend it to use the convention-based composition in MEF2 fairly easily. The MefConfig class is all that needed to change and then not by much.

```
/// <summary>
///     Responsible for configuring MEF for the application.
/// </summary>
public static class MefConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Registers MEF conventions and exports.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterMef()
    {
        // Register MVC/API conventions
        var registrationBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();
        registrationBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<Controller>().SetCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared).Export();
        registrationBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<ApiController>().SetCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared).Export();
        var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), registrationBuilder);
        var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(assemblyCatalog);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
        var resolver = new MefDependencyResolver(container);
        // Install MEF dependency resolver for MVC
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
        // Install MEF dependency resolver for Web API
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel compelled to comment, since someone voted up my answer here that there is a flaw and that is that you will get memory and connection leaks using the accepted answer. I have posted another question related to this which as of yet, there are no answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806239/how-to-properly-scope-composition-per-request-using-asp-net-mvc-webapi-and-mef. I have written my own solution which I will add to my question soon, especially if no one offers up another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this http://kennytordeur.blogspot.be/2012/08/mef-in-aspnet-mvc-4-and-webapi.html. It explains how to use MEF in an Asp.net MVC 4/Web Api project. There also exists a [Nuget package](http://kennytordeur.blogspot.be/2012/11/nuget-package-integrated-mef-in-aspnet.html) based on this code. That way you can test it very easily and quickly.

Comment: I looked at your blog post before coming up with my answer. I think the use of DefaultControllerFactory with MVC is now an outdated technique though, and one [should implement IDependencyResolver instead](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/21/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-dependencyresolver-and-controlleractivator.aspx). Besides, just linking to an external solution in an SO answer is best avoided.

Comment: Seems it's still there - but if it ever disappears again you can find at it https://web.archive.org/web/20180507160323/http://kennytordeur.blogspot.rs/2012/08/mef-in-aspnet-mvc-4-and-webapi.html

Answer (score 1):

@aknuds1's solution works, but leaks memory on *every API call*.
I've modified his solution to fix the leak.

```
public class MefDependencyResolver : System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer container;
    private readonly List<Lazy<object, object>> exports = new List<Lazy<object, object>>();
    private readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    public MefDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new MefDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to request a service implementation.
    /// 
    /// Here we call upon MEF to instantiate implementations of dependencies.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType">Type of service requested.</param>
    /// <returns>Service implementation or null.</returns>
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceType));

        var serviceExport = container.GetExports(serviceType, null, null).FirstOrDefault();
        if (serviceExport == null) return null;

        lock (this.syncRoot)
        {
            exports.Add(serviceExport);
        }

        return serviceExport.Value;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to request service implementations.
    /// 
    /// Here we call upon MEF to instantiate implementations of dependencies.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType">Type of service requested.</param>
    /// <returns>Service implementations.</returns>
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceType));

        var serviceExports = container.GetExports(serviceType, null, null);
        if (!serviceExports.Any()) return Enumerable.Empty<object>();

        lock (this.syncRoot)
        {
            exports.AddRange(serviceExports);
        }

        return serviceExports.Select(x => x.Value);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (this.syncRoot)
        {
            foreach (var e in exports)
            {
                this.container.ReleaseExport(e);
            }

            exports.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler approach that I'm using in my MVC4 project.

```
public static class MefConfig
{
     public static CompositionContainer MefContainer = null;

     public static void Initialise()
     {
          AggregateCatalog cat = new AggregateCatalog();
          cat.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
          MefContainer = new CompositionContainer(cat);
      }
}

public class MefFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      MefConfig.MefContainer.ComposeParts(filterContext.Controller);
   }        
}
```

In Application_Start run MefConfig.Initialise() and in FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) put filters.Add(new Filters.MefFilterAttribute());

Answer (score 0):

I followed @akanuds1's answer but I also had to change the ControllerFactory to this:

```
public class MefControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer compositionContainer;

    public MefControllerFactory(CompositionContainer compositionContainer)
    {
        this.compositionContainer = compositionContainer;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        var export = compositionContainer.GetExports(controllerType, null, null).SingleOrDefault();

        IController result;

        if (null != export)
        {
            result = export.Value as IController;
        }
        else
        {
            result = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            compositionContainer.ComposeParts(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Glogal.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    var container = MefConfig.Register();
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MefControllerFactory(container));
}
```