# MEF in WebApi 2.0 not resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, mef

I'm setting up MEF in a WebApi 2.0
Initially I looked at this example http://www.kennytordeur.blogspot.com/2012/08/mef-in-aspnet-mvc-4-and-webapi.html but in a more recent post [How to integrate MEF with ASP.NET MVC 4 and ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566688/how-to-integrate-mef-with-asp-net-mvc-4-and-asp-net-web-api) I saw that "DefaultControllerFactory with MVC is now an outdated technique".

I setup the MefDependencyResolver and the MefConfig based on the later post, but the webapi controller is not resolving it because the value is still null, also, I noticed the answer from the second post doesn't call compose parts. Does anyone know what I might be missing?

I'm calling MefConfig.RegisterMef() in an Owin Startup.cs class. Before in the startup class I had:

```
catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, true);
container.ComposeParts(this);
configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
configuration.DependencyResolver = new MefDependencyResolver(container);
app.UseWebApi(configuration);
```

With this other method, the import was still not being resolved. So I've tried those two things.

Comment: Were you able make this work? I am considering implementing pluggable WebAPI service and could not find anything on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I was checking the constructor, when I debug a different method the dependency has resolved.